# Why Are My Content Types Not Being Updated When I Deploy My WSP?

Tags: content-type

I have several content types defined in a custom feature. I have this feature working in both my dev & test environments. I needed to make some updates to the content types. When i deployed to my dev environment using Visual Studio, everything worked fine. When i packaged the feature in a WSP & deployed to my test environment, my content types were not updated (though all my other changes were deployed as expected).

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your content type has been deployed you can only change it by:

1. Use AddContentTypeField in FeatureUpgrading of your feature
2. Code
3. UI / SharePoint Designer

Just updating the xml for the content type will not work. Visual studio with it's conflict resolution will make you think it works, but it doesn't

Comment: Thanks. I feared that something like this had to be true, but i couldn't find any documentation one way or the other.